# Edge creates PDF files as a new browser

Tags: pdf, microsoft-edge

So I am more of a keyboard guy. Sometimes when I open two to three pdf in Edge it creates them as another application. For example

[image]

As you can see I have opened four PDFs in Edge now when I use alt+tab it shows like this

[image]

I wanted them like as you can see in Chrome I have opened some pdfs but it is showing it as only one tab. Can same be done with Edge?

Comment: You can find me [here on a meta.se chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1626/whatever-quid-meta-se). Missing you, @jitendra.  In 5-6 days, I'll be back in SE chats, and if I don't here from you before then, I'll seek you out in your room!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can prevent different Edge tabs appearing as separate alt-tab window options.

In windows settings search for 'Multi-tasking', then find the 'Alt + Tab' drop down and select 'Open windows only'.

[image: Multi-Tasking Settings]

Comment: Thank you so much